# How to make function back button in actionbar like back button in devices android

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

I have one activity in which there is a webview. when the webview goes to a few pages and I click the back button on the device runs fine, but if I click the back button in the actionbar then return it wrong.
can I make function back button in action bar like back button in the device?

this is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tes_backbutton);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv_tes);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.prgbarhome);

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(URL);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            //Required functionality here
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }
    });


    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //Show loader on url load
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(tes_backbutton.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(tes_backbutton.this, main_noconnect.class);
            tes_backbutton.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    view.canGoBack();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && view.canGoBack()) {
                view.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onOptionsItemSelected` method if you want to take any action after back arrow is clicked from action bar like below

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed(); //finishes the activity
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still not work, the back button in action bar is still not the same as the back button on the device. 
this function only returns to the previous activity, but if I click back button in device will return to previous page in webview but still in same activity. I want function back button in action bar like back button in device

Answer (score 0):

The 'back' button in the action bar **should** act differently than the device's back button. You don't want them both to do the same thing. The button in the action bar should serve as an 'up' button rather than a 'back' button. Please read more about [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: yes i think so,,  cause i use webview in my activity so the back button in action bar isn't back page inside webview :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use onBackPressed(); method

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
        mWebView.goBack();
      }else{
        onBackPressed(); //finishes the activity
      }
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use webview.cangoback() method for navigating between different web pages in webview 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
           if(view.cangoback()){
view.goback();
}
else{
finish();
}
break;






    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```